# esp32 - Ajax get multiple values

Tags: ajax, variables, arduino, webserver, esp32

I am trying to get multiple values from my ESP32 and display them on a webpage without refresh usign ajax. So far I have found only examples online that update only one vairable (see example below), but how can I update more than one variable?

code from my index.h file:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with regular interval
  getData();
}, 500); //500mSeconds update rate

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ADCValue").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readADC", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

in this sample ADCValue is written with the responsetext, but what if I have multiple values coming in?

Comment: You can have both values in the responsetext separated by a specific character e.g. `256-red` or you can use a structured data type like json.

Comment: JSON. use JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In esp32 server you need to response JSON message. Something like this

```
{"var1": "value1", "var1": "value2"}
```

Example code in ESP32

```
// Send headers
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-type: application/json");
client.println();

// Send http body
String var1 = "value1";
String var2 = "value2";
String jresp = "{\"var1\":\""+var1+"\",\"var1\":\""+var2+"\"}";
client.println(jresp);
client.println();
```

Finally, in your JS code, you can do something like this

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        try {
            var msg = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
            var var1 = msg.var1;
            var var2 = msg.var2;
            // You got 2 values above
        } catch (e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: why `onreadystatechange` and what is `http.readyState == 4`?

Comment: Please refer to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: there is  XMLHttpRequest.DONE and there is onload for success so no state checking is necessary

Comment: You are correct, but my answer is for the question, he is using onreadystatechange